# Text Water mark in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

hi all i have looked at answers to similar questions and none seem to work for me. I am trying to water mark an image from the camera (image in the below) and add an image and text as a water mark. The below is working perfectly for adding the image but have no idea how to do the text.

```
WmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"60.png"];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[WmarkImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(image.size.width - WmarkImage.size.width, image.size.height - WmarkImage.size.height, WmarkImage.size.width, WmarkImage.size.height)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[imageView setImage:image];
```

Comment: If you can get text as string then then put label and set correct font  and alpha as your requirement.

Comment: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12208-cgcontext-drawing-text-in-custom-view.html 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377034/write-text-on-image-view-image

check this

Comment: Search for 'burn text on image ios'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your text to image then merge them here is an code for this please check this.

```
NSString* kevin = @"Hello";
    UIFont* font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    CGSize size = [kevin sizeWithFont:font];
    // Create a bitmap context into which the text will be rendered.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    // Render the text
    [kevin drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];
    // Retrieve the image
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();



    UIImage *MergedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mark.png"];

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(200, 400);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [MergedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    // Apply supplied opacity if applicable
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 300, 400)];


    [imageView setImage:newImage];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: This one worked for me, hover i am getting 2 errors 1 ! sizeWithFont deprecated in ios7 : use sizeWithAttributes same error and response for drawAtPoint:withfont. BUT it compiles and runs fine on iPhone???

Comment: these are not errors these are only warning. deprecated in ios7 mean these methods are not used in iOS 7 they define new methods instead of them. check those new method in CGSize class

Answer (score 0):

This might help..

```
CATextLayer *theTextLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
theTextLayer.string = @"Your Text here";
theTextLayer.font = @"Helvetica";
theTextLayer.fontSize = @"12"
theTextLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
theTextLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);//give whatever width or height you want
[imageview.layer addSubLayer:theTextLayer];
```