# Watermark text is stretched and centered, which I don't want it to be (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a watermark text on top of an image, but the text is all stretched and the color is black even though it's set to white. Also, I'd like to place the text at the top of the image, so it kind of looks like a header. Right now it's centered.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653161/text-water-mark-in-xcode) solution, but obviously ran into some trouble...

Please help!

Here's my code:

```
//Watermark text.
NSMutableDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[stringAttributes setObject: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Book" size:20] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
[stringAttributes setObject: [UIColor whiteColor] forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[stringAttributes setObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0] forKey: NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
[stringAttributes setObject: [UIColor whiteColor] forKey: NSStrokeColorAttributeName];

NSString *myString = @"Hello";
CGSize size = [myString sizeWithAttributes:stringAttributes];
//Create a bitmap context into which the text will be rendered.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
//Render the text.
[myString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withAttributes:stringAttributes];
//Retrieve the image.
UIImage *imagene = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIImage *mergedImage = _imageView.image;

CGSize newSize = image.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

//Use existing opacity as is.
[mergedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];

//Apply supplied opacity if applicable.
[imagene drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

[imageView setImage:newImage];
self.imageView.image = newImage;

}
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed it was set to black, my bad... Fixed it. It's still stretched though, and centered. Any help appreciated :/

Comment: ContentMode of `imageView`?

Comment: @Larme It's not the image that is stretched, it's the text inside of it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imagene` is the image containing your text, and it is `size` big.

You then draw it at `newSize`, which is the size of the whole image. So you're stretching it. You need to draw it in a smaller rect, and probably centered, otherwise it will only be in the top left.

Instead of

```
[imagene drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];
```

Something like

```
CGRect drawingRect = (CGRect) {.size = size};
drawingRect.origin.x = (newSize.width - size.width) * 0.5;
drawingRect.origin.y = (newSize.height - size.height) * 0.5;
[imagene drawInRect:drawingRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];
```

You probably also want to be using the newer version of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` where you pass in a scale (use `0.0`) otherwise it will look terrible on retina screens.